# insert image grabbed from galleries/photos into my EditText before sending

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to grab an image from the galleries/photos and insert it in my EditText and sending it only after I click on the send button. I believe the title is self explanatory.

*Before opening this question thread, I tried to collect as much information from all others related questions found here in OverFlow.*

So far here is what I have:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = null;
        switch(requestCode) {
            case Constant.SELECT_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                    try {
                        yourSelectedImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (yourSelectedImage != null) {
                        typeMessageEditText.setCompoundDrawables(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), yourSelectedImage)
                                ,null, null, null);
                    }
                }
        }

        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case (R.id.insertPhotoImage):
                onStartGalleryPhotos();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    private void onStartGalleryPhotos() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, Constant.SELECT_PICTURE), Constant.SELECT_IMAGE);
    }
}
```

**DEBUG:**

`typeMessageEditText` is my EditText where I'm trying to get the image inserts. I tried debugging the onActivityResult and I'm seeing that the URI is actually being retrieved so I believe that part is working. However, when I convert my bitmap into a drawable and insert it in my EditText, nothing is actually showing in my EditText in my emulator.

Comment: I wonder what you would send if you did see the image. Try to just send it too.

Comment: Why not use a normal ImageView to display a Bitmap?

Comment: I have an EditText where the user inputs its message or picture. If the user wants to send a picture, the app should open the gallery/photos once the user clicks on the insert button. When the user selects a photo from the galleries, that photo should be returned inside the edittext before being sent.